# VSCODE Task Typescript TS5042 Build: Option 'project' cannot be mixed with source files on a command line

Tags: typescript, compilation, task, visual-studio-code

I am running a task defined in tasks.json using vscode to compile the typescripts files from a folder. But I kept getting the error "Typescript TS5042  Build: Option 'project' cannot be mixed with source files on a command line".

When I run this command from the command line(powershell) then it works fine!

My tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "CompileApp",
            "args": [
                "--p", "app/"
            ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following option to your tasks section "suppressTaskName". In your case it would look like this:

```
code
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "CompileApp",
            "args": [
                "--p", "app/"
            ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$tsc",
            "suppressTaskName": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Even after this the problem exists . so my task file is as follows , `{
         "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-w", "-p", ".", "ts"],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "isBackground": true,
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch",
    "suppressTaskName": true
}`

Comment: Did you run that command on the console and it worked correctly? I am talking about this command:

tsc -w -p . ts

It does not look like a correct way to call tsc to my. Can you take out the "ts" argument and try again?

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there any help on this issue ?